# Drawing lines with tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library, opencv

I'm working on a project that requires me to show a grid on an image, but my code keeps erroring saying 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'load'. The error is happening at the line `draw = ImageDraw.Draw(cv_img)`. Why is this happening?
`

```
import Tkinter
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageDraw
# Creates window
window = Tkinter.Tk()

# Load an image using OpenCV
cv_img = cv2.imread("P:\OneSky\United States.png", cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
window.title("United States Map")

# Get the image dimensions (OpenCV stores image data as NumPy ndarray)
height, width, no_channels = cv_img.shape

# Create a canvas that can fit the above image
canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(window, width = width, height = height)
canvas.pack()

# Use PIL (Pillow) to convert the NumPy ndarray to a PhotoImage
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = Image.fromarray(cv_img))

# Add a PhotoImage to the Canvas
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=photo, anchor=Tkinter.NW)

# Draws lines on map
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(cv_img)
x = cv_img.width/2
y_start = 0
y_end = cv_img.height
line = ((x,y_start), (x, y_end))
draw.line(line, fill=128)
del draw

# Run the window loop
window.mainloop()`
```

Comment: Have you tried including numpy ?

Comment: Try using `draw = ImageDraw.Draw(photo)`. `cv_img` is `numpy.ndarray` object, not a PIL image.

Comment: The parameter required by `ImageDraw.Draw()` should be the output of `Image.fromarray(cv_img)`.  Also you should do all the drawings before creating `photo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need opencv, try something like this instead:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("United States Map")
    steps = 25
    img = Image.open('P:\OneSky\United States.png').convert('RGB')

    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    y_start = 0
    y_end = img.height
    step_size = int(img.width / steps)

    for x in range(0, img.width, step_size):
        line = ((x, y_start), (x, y_end))
        draw.line(line, fill=128)

    x_start = 0
    x_end = img.width

    for y in range(0, img.height, step_size):
        line = ((x_start, y), (x_end, y))
        draw.line(line, fill=128)

    del draw
    display = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    label = tk.Label(root, image=display)
    label.pack()
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I got the idea for how to step the grid from [here](https://randomgeekery.org/2017/11/24/drawing-grids-with-python-and-pillow/).